# Is there any technique called "DLL Replacement"?

Tags: malware, dll

I know a techinique is called: [Process Replacement](http://www.codereversing.com/blog/?p=65) , I have searched but could not find any article about "DLL Replacement", in which malicious programs can replace a legal DLL (eg. a third party DLL) with a malicious DLL.

How does this work and are there any other techniques to do it?

Comment: What you are talking about is [DLL Hijacking](http://www.maravis.com/library/dll-hijacking-attacks/).

Comment: Nope, dll will be replaced in memory when it has been loaded in to process.

Comment: Replacing a DLL is over complicated task which can be easily simplified by other methods. Could you tell us that your actual end goal is for? I may able to offer you a more effective and simple solution.

Comment: When a DLL is loaded in memory in one process, and another process loads the same DLL, windows will map the (read only) code segment of the DLL into both processes. If you find a way to alter your "copy" of the code segment, this alteration would affect the other process as well; you could use this to cause the other process (which might have higher privileges) to execute your code. However, i wouldn't know how to turn this into an exploit; once you have the rights to modify segment descriptors, there's not much left that the other process can do but you can't.

Comment: @Guntram, to alter your copy would require access to the section object.  A simple VirtualProtect() will trigger a copy-on-write, and the remote process will not be affected.

Comment: @Paul: My process will check all hash of any DLLs which it loads, so can't simple replace a DLL like Extreme Coders recommended.

Comment: Though, even if you managed to replace the dll the .text section (which pretty much all anti-cheat systems and some complexed AVs) will check the .text disk against memory .text. Here is a tutorial on how .text memory and disk is done: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17636/Dynamic-TEXT-Section-Image-Verification

Comment: @Paul: Thank for a nice article. It's a detector and this is the other way of my question.
P/s: I've skim through this article, if dll have self-modifying code, the detector will wrong.

Comment: Do you want to replace system-wide or in some process?